# How to read very large text file(in gb's) in .net c# and split into small files

Tags: file, c#-4.0, filestream, large-files, memory-mapped-files

I'm tasked with reading a large text files(not XML's) may be in GB's in size. I need to split the file into smaller chunks by checking for the header . Suggest me some method to achieve this. Sample text structure will be

Sample large file
**header_start**
blaw
blaw
blawasasdasda
**header_start**
blaw
blawasdasda
blaw

Need to split into
1.txt
header_start
blaw
blaw
blawasasdasda

2.txt
header_start
blaw
blawasdasda
blaw

Please help me to achieve this in .net 4.0 with less time

Thanks
Vivek

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a `StreamReader` for the large file and call `ReadLine()` in a loop.
Maintain a `StreamWriter` for the current output file.
For each line, check whether it's a header, and, if it is, open a new target file in the `StreamWriter`.  If it isn't, just write that line to the current `StreamWriter`.

Comment: Thanks SLaks. Will it be faster. How about memory mapped files, can i use this in my case.